# How do I can optimize inserting/replacement element in to the List<string>

Tags: c#, collections

I have some code:

```
var result = new List<string>;
...
for (var i = 0; i < level; ++i)
  if (result.ElementAtOrDefault(i) == null)
     result.Insert(i, " " + positions[i]);
  else
     result[i] += " " + positions[i];
if (result.ElementAtOrDefault(level) == null)
   result.Insert(level, " " + currentPosition);
else
   result[level] += " " + currentPosition;
```

Can I do this without checking element for *null* from i-position? I need to add a part of string in i-position. But I have *"ArgumentOutOfRangeException"* if element wasn't created. Also method "insert" don't replace the element but push back it.

---

I tried to get data from *"ArgumentOutOfRangeException"* (which index called this exception) but I've failed.

Comment: why not compare `i` and `level` with _result.Count_?

Comment: It appears that perhaps you are confusing a List with an array? Lists do not have empty positions except positions greater than their length. Removing an item from a list does not create a hole, it creates a shorter list.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have 2 lists initialized as below:
            var positions = new List<int>();
            var result = new List<string>();
Why do I can't add elements using operator []?
positions[0] = value; positions[1] = value; ...

Comment: One more question. Why do I have the exception after initialization like this:
var positions = new List<int>(10); var result = new List<string>(10);
If I'm tried to do positions[0]=value?

Comment: [_The capacity of a List<T> is the number of elements that the List<T> can hold. As elements are added to a List<T>, the capacity is automatically increased as required by reallocating the internal array._](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: you can't add element with indexer, because [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx) _Gets or sets the element at the specified index._ and throw _ArgumentOutOfRangeException_ if _index is less than 0.
-or-
index is equal to or greater than Count._

Comment: @user3818229, can you explain what you try to do?

Comment: @Grundy I know what the capacity means. But I'm try to use second constructor with capacity value and it doesn't works. Why it compares with count -not- with capacity?

Comment: @user3818229 _The capacity of a List<T> is the number of elements that the List<T> can hold_, count - is real count elements in list, so if you not add elements in list you can't chahge it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce using `ElementAtOrDefault` with adding some condition like this

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < level && i < result.Count; ++i){
    //change existing items
    result[i] += " " + positions[i];
}

for (int j = 0, countAdd = level - result.Count; j < countAdd; ++j)
    //add new items
    result.Add(" " + positions[i+j]);

//add current
if (level >= result.Count)
    result.Add(" " + currentPosition);
else
    result[level] += " " + currentPosition;
```

Comment: This is not the equivalent code.
Do we have any alternative collections, which can be available after initialization? Or maybe insert method which override the old value?

Comment: @user3818229, are you try it and sure that it not equivalent?